# a jetty server app can work in eclipse but can't in Windows Console?

Tags: java, eclipse, jetty

I use Maven to built up a project,that contains only one Class-"App" with a "main" method,
the codes as follows:

```
org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server server = new Server();
WebAppContext webContext = new WebAppContext("D:/webroot/webapp", "/web");
server.setHandler(webContext);
server.start();
System.in.read();
```

This App can work properly in eclipse,and the webpage(jsp) can be browsed in Chrome.

Then I export this project to a "Runnable JAR file" use the options "Package required libraries into generated JAR",and after I run the jar file in Windows Console:
java -jar app.jar

The App can runing,but when I use Chrome to browse the webpage(jsp),it tell me an error:

HTTP ERROR 500
Problem accessing /web/. Reason:
java.err.nojdk
Caused by:

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.err.nojdk
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:89)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:375)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:116)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Jsr199JavaCompiler.compile(Jsr199JavaCompiler.java:198)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateClass(Compiler.java:364)

So how to make the jetty server app runing without eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem with Jetty `7.6.12.v20130726`. I switched to `7.4.5.v20110725` and problem gone.

This is source: http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-users/msg01588.html

Answer (score 3):

You may try this: in start.ini, find

```
Dorg.apache.jasper.compiler.disablejsr199=true
```

This config is enabled by default. You should disable it.

Comment: this (running `java -Dorg.apache.jasper...` ) when running in a standalone application (not in anyway related to eclipse) solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you should use JDK instead of JRE? Eclipse has its own jdk.

Comment: see this for more context on what I suspect your issue might be: http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-users/msg01590.html

Answer (score 0):

Choosing a JDK instead of a JRE to run Jetty solved this for me.

Using `jetty-distribution-7.6.13.v20130916`.